# Understanding interfaces and mocks in go

Tags: go, mocking

I am trying to build an abstraction for an AWS service ( ECR ). Here is the code:

```
type ECR struct {
    Client ecriface.ECRAPI
    Ctx    context.Context
}

// ECRCreate establishes aws session and creates a repo with provided input
func (e *ECR) ECRCreate(ecrInput *ecr.CreateRepositoryInput) {

    result, err := e.Client.CreateRepositoryWithContext(e.Ctx, ecrInput)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case ecr.ErrCodeServerException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeServerException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeInvalidTagParameterException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeInvalidTagParameterException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeTooManyTagsException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeTooManyTagsException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeRepositoryAlreadyExistsException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeRepositoryAlreadyExistsException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeLimitExceededException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeLimitExceededException, aerr.Error())
            case ecr.ErrCodeKmsException:
                log.Errorln(ecr.ErrCodeKmsException, aerr.Error())
            default:
                log.Errorln(aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
            // Message from an error.
            log.Errorln(err.Error())
        }
        return
    }
    log.Infof("Result: %v", result)
}
```

To mock aws sdk create repository call:

```
 type mockECRClient struct {
    ecriface.ECRAPI
}

func (m *mockECRClient) CreateRepositoryWithContext(ctx aws.Context, input *ecr.CreateRepositoryInput, opts ...request.Option) (*ecr.CreateRepositoryOutput, error) {
    createdAt := time.Now()
    encryptionType := "AES256"
    //awsMockAccount := "974589621236"
    encryptConfig := ecr.EncryptionConfiguration{EncryptionType: &encryptionType}
    imageScanConfig := input.ImageScanningConfiguration

    mockRepo := ecr.Repository{
        CreatedAt:                  &createdAt,
        EncryptionConfiguration:    &encryptConfig,
        ImageScanningConfiguration: imageScanConfig,
    }

    mockRepoOuput := ecr.CreateRepositoryOutput{Repository: &mockRepo}

    return &mockRepoOuput, nil

}

func TestECR_ECRCreate(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    mockSvc := &mockECRClient{}
    scan := true
    name := "Test1"
    inputTest1 := ecr.CreateRepositoryInput{
        RepositoryName:             &name,
        ImageScanningConfiguration: &ecr.ImageScanningConfiguration{ScanOnPush: &scan},
    }

    ecrTest := ECR{
        mockSvc,
        ctx,
    }

    ecrTest.ECRCreate(&inputTest1)
}
```

And this works. However, I am a bit confused around the usage of interface & composition here. ECRAPI is defined by ecriface package and I implement one of the signatures of the interface and still able to use mocked client `mockSvc`.
Questions:

- How does this work? Is this idiomatic way of mocking interfaces?
- What about the other methods of the `ECRAPI` interface? How are those taken care of ?

Is my understanding then correct, that we can define an interface with arbitrary number of method signatures, embed that interface into a struct and then pass the struct around where ever interface is expected. But then this means, I skip implementing other signatures of my interface?

I am thinking I am missing some important concept here, please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: this works because the function tested only calls the method you explicitly defined. It'll fail if it calls anything else.

This is how it happens:

The `mockECRClient` struct embeds the interface, so it has all the methods of that interface. However, to call any of those methods, you have to set that interface to an implementation:

```
x:=mockECRClient{}
x.ECRAPI=<real implementation of ECRAPI>
```

A call to x.Func() where `Func` is defined for `ECRAPI` will actually call `x.ECRAPI.Func()`. Since you didn't set ECRAPI, `x.ECRAPI` above is nil, and any method you call that uses the receiver will panic.

However, you defined a method for `mockECRClient`: `CreateRepositoryWithContext`. When you call `x.CreateRepositoryWithContext`, the method belongs to `x` and not to `x.ECRAPI`, and the receiver will be `x`, so it works.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. How does mockECR client then satisfy ecrapi interface since that is what I pass to ECR struct for the client field

Comment: Because of the embedded interface, it has all the methods of the ECRAPI.

Comment: Thank you @Burak! Appreciate the patience